# Only Win32 target is supported

Tags: c++, cygwin, mingw-w64

I am using cygwin64 and including the `MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include` folder in my project. However I am getting the following error when I run make on the project:

> /cygdrive/c/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/sys/types.h:10:2:
> error: #error Only Win32 target is supported!

I would think that that since the types.h file appears to be in a 64 bit folder it would support the 64 bit system, so what am I misunderstanding in this system?

The code in types.h that it gets caught on is as follows

```
#ifndef _WIN32
#error Only Win32 target is supported!
#endif
```

Comment: What you're missing is that these are `mingw32` files, as the directory name suggests. They're 64-bit *executables* of `mingw32`, which builds for 32-bit targets.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use the Cygwin C++ compiler? In any case, I think it would make sense that you also show how you invoke the compiler, so that we can see all the command line switches.