# GCC errors when trying to compile checkinstall on Cygwin

Tags: c, bash, gcc, cygwin

I'm running Cygwin on top of Windows 7. I'm having trouble trying to install the [`checkinstall`](http://checkinstall.izto.org/index.php) utility from source, and the culprit appears to be `gcc`.

When I run `/.configure`, I get the error:

```
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

So I continue with `make`, and get output that fails with lots of errors, presumably caused by `gcc`. The [output can be seen in its entirety here](https://pastebin.com/iNW7tgiv), but below are the first and last few lines of it.

```
$ make
    for file in locale/checkinstall-*.po ; do \
            case ${file} in \
                    locale/checkinstall-template.po)  ;; \
                    *) \
                            out=`echo $file | sed -s 's/po/mo/'` ; \
                            msgfmt -o ${out} ${file} ; \
                            if [ $? != 0 ] ; then \
                                    exit 1 ; \
                            fi ; \
                    ;; \
            esac ; \
    done
    make -C installwatch
    make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/b/Users/Me/Desktop/checkinstall-1.6.2/installwatch'
    gcc -Wall -c -D_GNU_SOURCE -DPIC -fPIC -D_REENTRANT -DVERSION=\"0.7.0beta7\" installwatch.c
   In file included from /usr/local/include/sys/param.h:33:0,
                    from installwatch.c:31:
   /usr/local/include/sys/types.h:10:2: error: #error Only Win32 target is supported!
    #error Only Win32 target is supported!
     ^~~~~
   In file included from /usr/local/include/sys/param.h:33:0,
                    from installwatch.c:31:
   /usr/local/include/sys/types.h:90:3: error: unknown type name ‘time_t’
      time_t  tv_sec; /* Seconds */
      ^~~~~~
   In file included from installwatch.c:33:0:
   /usr/local/include/sys/stat.h:10:2: error: #error Only Win32 target is supported!
    #error Only Win32 target is supported!
     ^~~~~
   In file included from /usr/local/include/sys/stat.h:14:0,
                    from installwatch.c:33:
   /usr/local/include/io.h:199:28: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘_findfirst32’
      _CRTIMP intptr_t __cdecl _findfirst32(const char *_Filename,struct _finddata32_t *_FindData);
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~ 


  ...           


    installwatch.c: In function ‘fopen’:
   installwatch.c:2560:51: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘result’
      logg("%" PRIdPTR "\tfopen\t%s\t#%s\n",(intptr_t)result,
                                                       ^~~~~~
    installwatch.c:2560:8: warning: format ‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument [-Wformat=]
       logg("%" PRIdPTR "\tfopen\t%s\t#%s\n",(intptr_t)result,
            ^~~
    installwatch.c:2560:8: warning: format ‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument [-Wformat=]
    installwatch.c:2575:51: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘result’
       logg("%" PRIdPTR "\tfopen\t%s\t#%s\n",(intptr_t)result,
                                                       ^~~~~~
    installwatch.c:2575:8: warning: format ‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument [-Wformat=]
       logg("%" PRIdPTR "\tfopen\t%s\t#%s\n",(intptr_t)result,
            ^~~
    installwatch.c:2575:8: warning: format ‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument [-Wformat=]
    installwatch.c: At top level:
    installwatch.c:2600:7: error: conflicting types for ‘getcwd’
     char *getcwd(char *buffer,size_t size) {
           ^~~~~~
    In file included from /usr/local/include/sys/stat.h:14:0,
                     from installwatch.c:33:
    /usr/local/include/io.h:279:17: note: previous declaration of ‘getcwd’ was here
       char *__cdecl getcwd (char *, int) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
                     ^~~~~~
    installwatch.c:2664:30: error: unknown type name ‘uid_t’
     int lchown(const char *path, uid_t owner, gid_t group) {
                                  ^~~~~
    installwatch.c:2664:43: error: unknown type name ‘gid_t’
     int lchown(const char *path, uid_t owner, gid_t group) {
                                               ^~~~~
    installwatch.c:2749:5: error: conflicting types for ‘mkdir’
     int mkdir(const char *pathname, mode_t mode) {
         ^~~~~
    In file included from /usr/local/include/sys/stat.h:14:0,
                     from installwatch.c:33:
    /usr/local/include/io.h:280:15: note: previous declaration of ‘mkdir’ was here
       int __cdecl mkdir (const char *) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
                   ^~~~~
    installwatch.c:2983:7: error: conflicting types for ‘realpath’
     char *realpath(const char *file_name,char *resolved_name) {
           ^~~~~~~~
    installwatch.c:556:6: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘realpath’ was here
      if(!realpath(path,resolved_path)) {
          ^~~~~~~~
    installwatch.c:3309:5: error: conflicting types for ‘utime’
     int utime (const char *pathname, const struct utimbuf *newtimes) {
         ^~~~~
    In file included from /usr/local/include/utime.h:6:0,
                     from installwatch.c:47:
    /usr/local/include/sys/utime.h:115:26: note: previous definition of ‘utime’ was here
     __CRT_INLINE int __cdecl utime(const char *_Filename,struct utimbuf *_Utimbuf) {
                              ^~~~~
    installwatch.c: In function ‘true_stat’:
    installwatch.c:153:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
     }
     ^
    installwatch.c: In function ‘true_lstat’:
    installwatch.c:161:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
     }
     ^
    installwatch.c: In function ‘true_mknod’:
    installwatch.c:157:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
     }
     ^
    In file included from installwatch.c:35:0:
    installwatch.c: In function ‘open’:
    installwatch.c:2842:20: warning: ‘mode_t {aka short unsigned int}’ is promoted to ‘int’ when passed through ‘...’
      mode = va_arg(ap, mode_t);
                        ^
    installwatch.c:2842:20: note: (so you should pass ‘int’ not ‘mode_t {aka short unsigned int}’ to ‘va_arg’)
    installwatch.c:2842:20: note: if this code is reached, the program will abort
    At top level:
    installwatch.c:1040:12: warning: ‘__instw_printdirent64’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
     static int __instw_printdirent64(struct dirent64 *entry) {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    make[1]: *** [Makefile:22: installwatch.o] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/b/Users/Me/Desktop/checkinstall-1.6.2/installwatch'
    make: *** [Makefile:11: all] Error 2
```

I'm sorry in advance if I'm going about this the wrong way, but I'm completely out of my depth with this code and the errors being thrown. I've tried using the Cygwin installer to reinstall `gcc_core` and other `gcc` packages several times to no effect.

I was in the process of using [this guide](http://preshing.com/20141108/how-to-install-the-latest-gcc-on-windows/) to compile the latest version of `gcc` from source before I ran into fatal errors with that too, and decided to start from the beginning and determine whether the problem can be solved without adding yet more bloat to my Cygwin installation. Thanks in advance, it's much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see anything above that indicates a problem with `gcc`. `gcc` is reporting the errors it's encountering while trying to compile and build the utility. It should come with directions about how to compile. If there's a `configure` script to run, find that first. `bash` is telling you it can't find it. The rest of the `#error` seems to indicate to me that you can only compile this on native Windows (not in Cygwin), but I don't know for sure. If it doesn't come with compile instructions, contacting the author should be helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703526/error-only-win32-target-is-supported and try autoconf checkinstall.in instead of configure

Comment: as the package is not using autoconf/automake of course configure and company are missing.

Comment: @gj13 So how would I resolve the problem outlined in that question?

Comment: Your `types.h` is installed in `/usr/local/`, what package is it from?  That is potentially why installing `gcc` and others have no effect.  It will use the one from `/usr/local/` first, which is probably not the one it should be using.

Comment: @pak - I've downloaded and reinstalled a lot of packages over the last week, many of them containing compilers. The only way I know to be sure which package it belongs to is `apt-cyg search /usr/local/include/sys/types.h` but doing that returns nothing. Is there another way to determine this? Also, I'm not sure whether it's relevant but doing a search for types.h returns several different files, although only the one being used by `make` above is in /usr/local:

https://i.imgur.com/8RO0qKY.jpg

Comment: Well, what have you manually compiled and installed not using the setup program?  That's what would be installed into /usr/local.  You might just get rid of all those local headers that gcc complains about.

Comment: @pak - At this point, I honestly have no idea, I didn't think I'd need to keep track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `checkinstall` app does not appear to be configured to run on `cygwin`. It is configured for several specific Linux distribution families, and has a generic source release.

I have downloaded and unpacked the `checkinstall-1.6.2.tar.gz` file; it expands into the `checkinstall-1.6.2` directory. There you find the `checkinstall` shell script. I don't have the time to wade through several thousand lines of shell code. It appears to require you build and install the `installwatch` program, which I guess will register a file change handler in order to identify all new and changed files and directories. I suspect that handler would need to change to work properly in cygwin. You might have success posting to one of the [Cygwin mailing lists](https://cygwin.com/lists.html).

HTH

Doug

Comment: I concluded this yesterday, after I spent several hours stripping my Cygwin installation to the bare minimum, and then rebuilding it at a file at a time until I was able to get the smallest number of errors from `make`. The errors left standing were still fatal enough that I had no choice but to conclude `checkinstall` was either not meant to built from source or was not meant to be built for Cygwin.